# How to execute code line by line in a subscription in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I noticed the code in the else section was running before the code in the if(i<1) section had completed even though i<1 has run first. The issue is that the user cannot be found if it isnt input into the array yet. Is there a way to make sure the first iteration of this loop has completed?

```
for (let i=0; i<roles.length; i++) {
  this.databaseService.addUsers(newRole).subscribe(
    response => {
      if (i<1) {
        let newUser = new User(newRole.userName);
        newUser.children = [newRole];
        this.users.push(newUser);
        this.dataGrid.data = this.users;
      } else {
        this.roles.push(newRole);
        this.users.find(c => c.name === dialogComponent.userName).children.push(newRole);
        this.dataGrid.data = this.users;
      } 
    },
    error => console.log(error)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) can be used to wait for multiple Oversables to complete. You can put the Observables into an array inside the for-loop and pass that array into the `forkJoin`

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

const allRequests: Observable<*/ put your response type here */> = []

for (let i=0; i<roles.length; i++) {
  allRequests.push(this.databaseService.addUsers(newRole))
}

forkJoin(allRequests).subscribe(responses => {
  responses.forEach((response, i) => {
    if (i < 1) {
        let newUser = new User(newRole.userName);
        newUser.children = [newRole];
        this.users.push(newUser);
        this.dataGrid.data = this.users;
      } else {
        this.roles.push(newRole);
        this.users.find(
          c => c.name === dialogComponent.userName
        ).children.push(newRole);
        this.dataGrid.data = this.users;
    } 
  })
}, error => console.log(error))
```

The subscription callback executes only *after* all Observables have completed. The `forEach` loop will run in sequence now.

Comment: you can use tap to  debug  a  rxjs stream